# ????? while trying to print Arabic characters using escpos encoder in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, encoding, bluetooth, arabic

I tried printing a receipt using ionic-bluetooth-serial and  ESCPOS encoder to encode my data.  I am able to print  english characters.But when i tried to print an arabic characters, it was printing as ????.

Answer (score 0):

try to create canvas image with arabic characters and print it using escpos:

```
const {
    createCanvas,
    loadImage,
    Image
} = require('canvas');
var escpos = require('escpos');

canvas = createCanvas(580, 700)
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.font = "30px bold";
ctx.fillText('مرحبا بالعالم', 50, 50);

device.open(function() {
    escpos.Image.load(canvas.toDataURL(), function(rasterimage) {
        printer.raster(rasterimage)
        printer.cut()
        printer.close()
    });
});
```

there is an open issue on github : https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/EscPosEncoder/issues/4